# ¿Cómo puedo cerrar todos los archivos que esté usando en Vim con NERDTree y guardar cambios sin hacerlo uno a uno?

Tags: java, ubuntu, vim

En resumen es: tengo el pluggin NERDTree en Vim, y al usarlo se abren varios buffers que pertenecen a las clases que estoy usando y eso. Cuando quiero compilar para probar si las cosas van bien, tengo que cerrar cada pestaña de manera manual y es una pérdida de tiempo. Quisiera saber si hay alguna combinación de teclas que me permitan guardar y cerrar todo de una para ahorrarme todo esto que mencioné

Antes de esto busqué y una página (https://geekland.eu/cerrar-todas-las-ventanas-abiertas-de-golpe/) da una solución, pero sinceramente me parece muy allá para un problema tan simple.

Comment: La pregunta es un poco ambigua, dificil de entender. Intenta ser un poco más específico, por favor, te sugiero leer [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Puedes editar la pregunta :)

Answer (score 1):

En Vim, cada archivo abierto se lo conoce como "buffer", para salvar todos los buffers que tuvieran algún cambio:

```
:wa
```

Es decir, "write all". Para cerrar el buffer actual:

```
:bd
```

Es decir, "buffer delete", si quieres hacerlo con todos los "buffers" abiertos, puedes usar [`bufdo`](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Run_a_command_in_multiple_buffers#Bufdo)

```
:bufdo bd
```